# Knockout check box binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to have a checkbox update the value of an observable. This partially works, but the checkbox does not "check" itself after. To solve this I tried to add the checked: binding, looking for the value that I had just set in the click event, but this also does not work.

My Observable

```
appViewModel.test = ko.observable(1);
```

The checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox"  data-bind="checked: test() == 4, click: test.bind($data, 4)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a computed to catch observable changes:

```
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
    var self = this;
    this.checked = ko.observable(false);
    this.test = ko.observable();
    this.isChecked = ko.computed(function(){
        var test = self.test();
        if(test === '4')
        {
            self.checked(true);
            return;
        }
        self.checked(false);
    });
};
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dw4v1axr/1/)

Comment: I am trying to have a checkbox be "checked" based on the value of an observable that isn't a Boolean. So for instance if I had an observable variable called test, I want the checkbox to be checked only if test is (or becomes) equal to 4. I do not see in your example that this is happening. Your checkbox is checking a true or false value.

Comment: Similar idea, you can just switch them around. I updated the fiddler for an example. Enter 4 into a text box

Answer (score 0):

The `checked` binding wants to be two-way, writable as well as readable. It can't write to a test, though, when you click it. Instead of having a click binding, you should have the test set to 4 by the write function of the computed you use as the `checked` binding.

```js
var vm = {
  test: ko.observable(1)
};
vm.checked = ko.computed({
  read: function () { return vm.test() == 4; },
  write: function (newValue) {
    vm.test(newValue ? 4 : 1);
  }
});
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox"  data-bind="checked: checked"/>
<div data-bind="text:test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a click handler that checks to see if the value is 4 (or whatever arbitrary value you want) and then can act accordingly, like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkBoxValue() === 4, 
                                  click: handleCheckBoxClick">
<br/>
<div> 
    <span>Debug:</span>
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.checkBoxValue = ko.observable(0);
    self.handleCheckBoxClick = function () {
        if (self.checkBoxValue() !== 4) {
            self.checkBoxValue(4);
        } else {
            self.checkBoxValue(0);
        }

        return true;
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

*Note:* I added the debug output so you could see the underlying `checkBoxValue` value in the view model as you interact with the checkbox.

See [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dw4v1axr/)